# how to validate the count between nested json file and dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a nested json file in my blob storage which I'm reading through databricks using read_json
and loading into dataframe.
I need to create a test case like whether all records present in json file is loaded to dataframe.

how to check if all the records present in nested json file is loaded?
is their a way to count number of records in nested json file using python?

sample json:

```
{ 
    "coffee": {
        "region": [
            {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
            {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
        ],
        "country": {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    }, 
    "brewing": {
        "region": [
            {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
            {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
        ],
        "country": {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    }


}
```

Comment: You should include a minimal example of your JSON, the result you need, and what you've tried so far

Comment: i included the sample json now, want to know like if i load this json records to dataframe, how to validate if all these records are loaded to dataframe. wanted to compare between the number of records in json and dataframe.

Comment: in my case its billions of lines in json,  so want to know how to count the number of records in json for validation wrt dataframe